# Mysql query takes too much time with Index

Tags: mysql

My query takes too much time with index.
How to create a good index for my Mysql query?

**Query**

```
SELECT `id`, `time`, `volume`, `candle` FROM `forex_history` 
WHERE 
   period='30m' AND 
   id IN ('40','1817') 
   ORDER BY `time` DESC 
LIMIT 600;
```

95 million rows in the table

Slow query log:

```
# Query_time: 3.801843  Lock_time: 0.000076  Rows_sent: 600  Rows_examined: 10966
# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 49296
```

10% queries are slow.
Query takes 0.2 Sec to 30 Sec

Table schema:

[image]

Execution plan:

[image]

Comment: Run  `explain select ...` to see the execution plan.

Comment: I just learn "explain select..." today, Can you please check its result for me.. Thanks. screenshot http://prntscr.com/pooyu7

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON forex_history (period, time, volume, candle);
-- add id if not using InnoDB
```

This index would cover the entire `WHERE` clause as well as the `SELECT`.

Two other versions you may try:

```
(period, id, time, volume, candle)
(period, id, time)
```

Comment: I know it will not work, but try for you, And result is "Not working". I didn't down vote, but column name can't be an index, index only work on where clause. Please explain if you think, select columns can be in index.

Comment: @FaisalAbbas Your understanding of how indices work is far off, telling by your comment.  Because your select only includes 4 columns, I choose to cover these columns by including all of them in the index.

Comment: In fact, it may not work, but the answer I gave is reasonable guess without knowing your data, its cardinality, etc.

Comment: Your index is active, but i didn't delete my old index, i will update you tomorrow, if Query log, log slow query. I am afraid if i delete my index, my server will dead due to query heavy load.

Comment: Without my index query takes 50+ seconds to load.

Answer (score 0):

I am in agreement with Tim's answer... most specifically the index on (period, id, time).

Also, since your "id" column is integer, get rid of the quotes making it an implied string.  Let the data types be correct to prevent type/cast confusion.

```
SELECT id, time, volume,  candle 
   FROM forex_history
   WHERE period='30m' 
      AND id IN ( 40, 1817 ) 
   ORDER BY time DESC 
   LIMIT 600;
```

Now, as Tim also mentioned about cardinality, we don't have any idea about that and your data set.  You might be best to do a UNION, then limit.  Here's why.  You have 95+ million records.  Lets say ID 40 has 180k records and id 1817 has another 90k records.  You have to pull down over 270k records before you can apply the order.

If you do a union where each individual ID has a limit of 600, you will get at MOST 1200 records, then those 1200 records are sorted by their respective best times descending even if it is all one-sided for a given ID.

```
SELECT 
      id, time, volume,  candle 
   from
      ( SELECT id, time, volume,  candle 
           FROM forex_history
           WHERE period='30m' 
              AND id = 40 
           ORDER BY time DESC 
           LIMIT 600
        UNION ALL
        SELECT id, time, volume,  candle 
           FROM forex_history
           WHERE period='30m' 
              AND id = 1817
           ORDER BY time DESC 
           LIMIT 600 ) PQ
   order by time desc
   limit 600
```

Answer (score -1):

Convert Time to Number and create index on time.